# Returning a subset of results from Crystal Report dataset

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, for-loop, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report which gathers a list of tax codes and various projects they are used on, using a SQL stored procedure as the primary dataset. The report allows the user to select a list of Tax Codes as a parameter.

I am trying to have a Formula Field up at the Report Header level that will show all Tax Codes from the parameter list which *were not* found in the SP's results. The user has a date range as a parameter so some tax code use falls outside of that. For example, if the Tax Code parameters are:

**CA72, WA2191, WA199, IN2318**

After the SP runs, let's say it only has CA72 and WA199 in the results. I want the Formula to output: "Not Found: WA2191, IN2318"

I have it partially working, depending on where I place the formula. It only seems to look at the immediate result set in the group. When I place it in the Report Header, it shows everything missing *except* for the first Tax Code group found. If I put it at the end, it shows everything missing except for the last Tax Code group found. I don't know where to place it so it evaluates on the whole report data and not just one group.

This is what I currently have, any suggestions/advice on how to fix this would be amazing. Still very new to crystal reports:

```
StringVar taxOutStr := "Not Found: ";
for i := 1 to count({?TaxCodes}) do
(
    IF NOT({?TaxCodes}[i] IN {BD_HQTX_EmpByTaxCode;1.TaxCode})
    THEN taxOutStr := taxOutStr + {?TaxCodes}[i] + ", "
    ELSE ""
);

taxOutStr;
```

Comment: People are still using crystal reports?  I'm sorry.

Comment: One problem you will have trying this in the header is that the header is written before the entire dataset has been read, so a portion of the relevant data is essentially out of scope within the header.

Comment: If you do need this in the header, it might require a subreport.  I'm thinking it would be possible to use a subreport to read the dataset one record at a time, while also removing Tax Codes from your parameter list as they are read in the data set.  Then at the end of the subreport the tax codes that remain in your parameter set are the ones that were not found in your data.

Comment: If position is the key, then shouldn't placing it in the report footer process all of the data? When I place it there, it only seems to process the last group. I haven't done much with subreports before, I'll do some research there and see if that's the way